# What's wrong in this Angularjs code?

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple angular</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">

        <h1>{{a.name}}</h1>

    </div>

    <script>
    function MyController($scope) {
        $scope.a = {
            'name':"fox",
            'title':'hello'
        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

- i'm learning angularjs. Could you tell me what's wrong with this code?
- I'm getting the output as "a.name" instead of 'fox'

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular 1.3 and newer you can't use global functions as controllers

Comment: Version of Angular: 1.3.x

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using Angular 1.3, you need to "attach" your controllers to your module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp"> //Change #1: need to write your app here

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple angular</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">

        <h1>{{a.name}}</h1>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []); //Change #2: declare your app

    function MyController($scope) {
        $scope.a = {
        'name':"fox",
        'title':'hello'
       }
    }

    app.controller("MyController", MyController); //Change #3: attach your controller

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

A total of 3 adjustments needed to your code.